# Overriding a magit Keybinding using evil-mode and bind-map

Tags: key-bindings, magit, evil

I am using evil-mode, magit, evil-magit, and bind-map.

I have defined a map with bind-map using `SPC` as my `:evil-keys` similarly to what spacemacs provides.

Magit defines `SPC` as `magit-diff-show-or-scroll-up` and I'm having a rough time trying to override that binding or make my bind-map take precedence so I can invoke my leader key.

I have tried to deduce how spacemacs handles this issue but I believe it may be within their evilified* functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it sounds to me like you have `SPC` bound in one of the global evil maps (through bind-map), like `evil-normal-state-map`. evil-magit makes `magit-mode-map` an overriding map which makes its bindings shadow the global evil ones. Therefore, you need to bind `SPC` at a precedence level that matches or exceeds this. There are at least two ways to do this.

1. Bind your `my-map` (whatever you call it) directly in `magit-mode-map` for the state you want, using something like `(evil-define-key 'normal magit-mode-map (kbd "SPC") my-map)`. This will target just the purpose you outlined.
2. Try adding `:override-minor-modes t` to your `bind-map` declaration, which essentially elevates the precedence of that binding globally. This could change the way your bindings work in other modes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first one and it solved my issue. I will keep the second one in mind. I actually had a variation of the first one in my config but I used "motion" instead of "normal".